# How to speed up the development experience with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, performance, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I've gotten thrown into a WebForms ASP.NET 3.5 project on VS2008.  The solution has 5 projects, so not too large.  One thing that really annoys me is how long it takes go to from F5 to an actual web page that I can do something about (good 15-20 seconds). The box I am on is relatively recent - everything else on it feels really snappy.

What are some of the things I can do to speed up this process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need to debug, don't do it. What I do is start the project without debugging (ctrl + F5). you've now got a window attached to VS. All you need to do now is rebuild your code when you make code changes, which is much quicker.

Simon

Answer (score 3):

1. Directly reference the dlls instead of the projects.(If the referenced projects are compiled in release mode that's better)
2. Set optimizeCompilations=”true” :
   When you experience very slow performance on
   an initial request to an ASP.NET Web site after you change the
   App_Code folder, the bin folder, or the Global.asax file.Turning on this flag will improve the performance.
3. Use Combress (http://combres.codeplex.com/) to minify css and javascript files.
4. Enable Gzip compression to reduce the network traffic on the network.This may reduce the network traffic by more than 50%.
5. http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html.
   try to implement the best coding practices.

These things will definitely improve the performance of the site.